# How pass multiple body parameters in wcf rest using webinvoke method(Post or PUT)

Tags: wcf, parameter-passing, webinvoke

I have written a  REST Service in WCF in which I have created a method(PUT) to update a user. for this method I need to pass multiple body parameters

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", UriTemplate = "users/user",BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
[OperationContract]
public bool UpdateUserAccount(User user,int friendUserID)
{
    //do something
    return restult;
}
```

Although I can pass an XML entity of user class if there is only one parameter. as following:

```
var myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serviceUrl);
myRequest.Method = "PUT";
myRequest.ContentType = "application/xml";
byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
myRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;
//add the data to be posted in the request stream
var requestStream = myRequest.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
requestStream.Close();
```

but how to pass another parameter(friendUserID) value?
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For all method types except GET only one parameter can be sent as the data item. So either move the parameter to querystring

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", UriTemplate = "users/user/{friendUserID}",BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
[OperationContract]
public bool UpdateUserAccount(User user, int friendUserID)
{
    //do something
    return restult;
}
```

or add the parameter as node in the request data

```
<UpdateUserAccount xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <User>
        ...
    </User>
    <friendUserID>12345</friendUserID>
</UUpdateUserAccount>
```