# Post json object from C# client and read from WCF service in .Net 3.5

Tags: c#, json, web-services, wcf, .net-3.5

I want to send json object from C# client (using `WebRequest` or any other method .Net 3.5 support) to WCF service and read that object from there. Can anybody help?

Comment: You mean to say that client want to consume WCF service using JSON psot... Right?

Comment: What have u tried so far? What error/issue you are getting while sending the JSON Object.

Comment: @AmitSoni No. Json request from client to WCF and deserialize it in the server.

Comment: @Mohit Shrivastava I haven't try so far. I only tried WCF service to client using `WebRequest `

Comment: It's so easy to down vote without answering....

Answer (score 0):

You can use Newtonsoft.Json package from NuGet to help you accomplish this.
To deserialize your json back to the object in WCF you can do:

```
  List<T> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonString);
  //assuming you have a list of objects.
```

To convert the object to Json string you will have to do:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj)
```

Refer to this for posting data to wcf from c#

[How to post to wcf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357092/http-post-to-a-wcf-service)

Comment: Actually I'm using Json.net. I just want to know how to send data client to server through `WebRequest` and `StreamWriter`. Not how serialize or deserialize. Anyway thanks.